# Add new columns on existing or auxiliary table?

Tags: mysql, optimization

I have a database with the following table:

```
stores
- ID
- name
- phone number
- email address
```

After adding around 4000 stores to the database we figured that we will need to allow store owners to create a more complete profile. This means we will have the following optional fields:

```
address, zip code, description  and website URL
```

My question: should I add these new columns on the existing table or create a new one called store_details, with a foreign key to main table?

I am using MySQL, and each store can only have 1 of those fields.

Consider that only 30% of store owners are going to use them by creating a complete profile.

I am mostly worried with performance when the database grows to say 500,000 entries. For example, when fetching all stores to perform a keyword search. One could argue that by using an axillary table I could save some memory both on disk and on RAM when manipulating the data, but not not sure if this is significant or not.

Comment: What database platform are you using? You might get different answers. I assume a single store will never need multiple addresses?

Comment: @BradC MySQL and correct.

Comment: Keyword search -- This can be done in efficient ways or in terribly inefficient ways.  Think about it _now_; the `JOIN` could make a difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't specified a database platform, but my experience with MS SQL server is that you should put those fields in the same table, unless you need them separate for other reasons (like if a single store can have multiple addresses).

Any performance concerns you have can likely be resolved with proper indexing, based on how you believe the table will be queried.

Comment: That is what I suspected. Thanks!